# MP4 corrupted, how to repair?

Tags: video, file-corruption, video-codecs

I recorded two videos on a digital camera. Both videos were saved using identical codecs and settings.

The second video is corrupted, in some way, and I can't open with VLC or video-editing software.
(The first video is ok).

I tried to convert video with "video to video" software that says:

```
#8636.3: [h264 @ 04E10060]AVC: nal size -1920576098
#8636.3: [h264 @ 04E10060]no frame!
#8636.5: [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 04EC4020]decoding for stream 0 failed
#8636.4: [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 04EC4020]Could not find codec parameters 
for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), 1920x1080, 11987 kb/s): 
 unspecified pixel format
#8636.4: Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 
 'probesize' options

***File load error: C:\..\PICT0002.MP4: could not find codec parameters
```

Analyzing with Gspot, on videos (video corrupted on the right: PICT0002):

[image]

Can anyone suggest a tool or a method to repair the second video?
The size is correct (3 GB), and when I try to open it with VLC, the length seems to be ok (40 min).

Theoretically: Should I change codec-metadata in the file to make it recognizable by software?

***UPDATE***

tried ffmpeg analysis.
command: 
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2000000000 -i PICT0002.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy PICT0002-fixed.mp4

response:

```
C:\Programmi\ffmpeg\bin>ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2000000000 -i PICT0002.mp4 - 
c:v libx264 -c:a copy PICT0002-fixed.mp4
ffmpeg version N-91398-gd08d4a8c73 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg         
developers
   built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable- 
   bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass 
   --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable- 
   libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg -- 
   enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr -- 
   enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack 
   --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 -- 
   enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable- 
   libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa 
   --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx -- 
   enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable- 
   nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
      libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
      libavcodec     58. 20.104 / 58. 20.104
      libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
      libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
      libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
      libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
      libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
      libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
 [h264 @ 000002036235d380] Invalid NAL unit size (-1920576098 > 197632).
 [h264 @ 000002036235d380] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002036234a300] decoding for stream 0 failed
 [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002036234a300] Could not find codec 
 parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 
 11987 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
 Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' 
  options
 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'PICT0002.mp4':
   Metadata:
   major_brand     : avc1
   minor_version   : 0
   compatible_brands: avc1isom
   creation_time   : 2021-06-30T08:32:50.000000Z
   Duration: 00:40:53.45, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12122 kb/s
   Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 11987 
    kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
   Metadata:
     creation_time   : 2021-06-30T08:32:50.000000Z
     handler_name    :  Ambarella AVC
     encoder         : Ambarella AVC encoder
 Stream mapping:
   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
 Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 [h264 @ 000002036234dd40] Invalid NAL unit size (-1920576098 > 197632).
 [h264 @ 000002036234dd40] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
 [h264 @ 0000020363f92300] Invalid NAL unit size (1565499804 > 10496).
 [h264 @ 0000020363f92300] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
 Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
     Last message repeated one time
 Cannot determine the format of input stream 0:0 after EOF
 Error marking filters as finished
 Conversion failed!
```

So, the conversion failed.

Comment: Judging by the log output, the software you are using appears to be FFmpeg (or based on FFmpeg). Try to add the flag `-analyzeduration 2000000000` to the FFmpeg arguments. It's worth noting the VLC player is also based on FFmpeg... and thus they share similar limitations in their default configurations.

Comment: how to do in windows 10? (tank you)

Comment: Well, you said you were using "video to video" software to convert the video. What software is that? Does it have a name? If you want to use FFmpeg directly (high learning curve) you can download the latest windows builds here: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ . It's a command line tool, so you will have to run the "ffmpeg prompt" and execute the appropriate command. Something like: `ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2000000000 -i PICT0002.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy PICT0002-fixed.mp4` should do it.

Comment: http://www.videotovideo.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION.**

First of all, tank you to Ricardo Bohner.
He refers to Video [Repair Tool](http://grauonline.de/cms2/?page_id=5).

Going to that site, you'll find that this tool is not any more available, and you should subscribe to [Restore Media](https://restore.media/).

In alternative you can go [here](https://www.videohelp.com/software/recover-mp4-to-h264).
I followed instruction showed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3nWw9aX5kw).

Sadly I recovered only 30:00 mins of 40:00 mins of the video,
but the recovered part is perfect.

Hope this can be usefull.

**UPDATE:**
As explained by Riccardo Bonher (see below in comments), it's possible to use a trick (doubling mp4 lenght) and recover it by [Repair Tool](http://grauonline.de/cms2/?page_id=5).

In this way I was able to repair all length of the corrupted-mp4.
After doing this I was able to see video with VLC (video-reader)..

..but I was not still able to convert it by editing-softare (as VirtualDub, Video to Video etc.)

So, I used a combinated procedure:
A) using Riccardo solution (as explained in comments) for recovreing whole video-length
B) repassing recovered video by my original solution (recover-mp4-to-h264.zip), for making it correct and readable by common editing-softwares.
Hope this can help people..

Comment: Marco, what do mean with no longer available? I just downloaded it. Here is the direct download link: http://grauonline.de/download/videorepair.zip

Comment: I read that version is a demo. It recovers only half video.

Comment: Yes, but there is trick on how to recover 100% instead of 50%:

Rename your damaged video file to 1.mp4 make a copy of it and name it 2.mp4. Open a command prompt, enter the path where the 2 video files are and type the following command:

copy /b 1.mp4+2.mp4 double.mp4

This will create a video called double.mp4 which will have double the lenght of your original damaged video. Open this file in the Video repair tool and have it fixed, it will recover 100% of your video.

Comment: Tank you Riccardo, in this way I recovered all the 40 min! I've not your creativity..

Comment: Really? I was just up to recall my copy /b tip cause I figured out it doesn't work for mp4 files. When you do the copy /b trick with mp4 files it only doubles the filesize in my test but not the video lenght. I was going to suggest you to use AVIDemux or other video editing software that permits to append a video to another video.

So the tip would be to make a copy of the video then append the two using a video editing software and then use the video repair tool to restrore the damaged video doubled in size (80min).

But happy to know that it worked anyway.

Comment: Little correction, with your trick the mp4 was repaired entirely (and visible to vlc), but I was not able to convert it (I must convert it with a smaller codec too). So I reused the recover-mp4-to-h264.zip (as my first solution) to pass the recovered version. Now I can use the video with common conversion-tools & sofware (as Virtualdub, videoToVideo etc).

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tool: [Video Repair Tool](http://grauonline.de/cms2/?page_id=5)

It is not freeware but it repairs 50% of your video for free so you'll know if it works.

Check also this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QK3vizVIds